# How to use npm packages from Github package registry with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, github, npm, package

Jenkins can't find packages from the Github registry despite authorisation to access the Github organisations packages and the namespace being named in the `.npmrc` and `.yarnrc` files.

Build is failing with the following error:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.npmjs.org/@git+https:%2f/****: Request \"https://registry.npmjs.org/@git+https:%2f/****\" returned a 405".
error Couldn't find package "@git+https://****" on the "npm" registry.
```

Jenkins seems to only look for packages on npm's registry and ignore the npmrc file. The Jenkins docs don't seem to mention Github packages. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set registry using the below in your Jenkinsfile.

```
npm config set registry https://registry.foo.bar.com
```

OR directly issue install like below.

```
npm install --registry https://registry.foo.bar.com
```

Jenkinsfile stage sample:

```
     stage('NPM Installation') {
          steps {
              container('nodejs) {
                sh '''
                  npm install --registry=https://registry.foo.bar.com
               '''
            }
          }
        }
```

If you're trying to authenticate to your private github packages, then follow the steps listed here --> [Authenticating-with-a-personal-access-token](https://help.github.com/en/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-npm-for-use-with-github-packages#authenticating-with-a-personal-access-token)

Comment: Sorry, only just saw your response now!
We only have certain packages hosted there though, all other packages should still come from npmjs.org.

Comment: @Jacob 
1.You can try npm's scoped packages. You can scope those certain packages of yours while publishing and install them using the scope [Scope-Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes). 2. Set aliases for different npm registries you have & set them before npm install.3. Or do npm install <packages to install> --registry=your-private-registry and npm install --registry=your-public-registry.